# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py_entitymatching'

Tags: python, pycharm

Error while installing py_entitymatching package in pycharm.

PyCharm : 2020.2.3

Python : 3.6

[image]

Comment: Did you try to run `pip install py-entitymatching` in the PyCharm's terminal?

Comment: @VukašinManojlović I tried that but I get following error. error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------

Comment: Why don't you follow the link, install Microsoft C++ Build Tools, restart the computer and try installing again?

Answer (score 1):

The package could be installed on another interpreter. I've had this issue with Pycharm before, where if a package was installed on one interpreter I could not install it / access it when using a different interpreter.

Comment: I have only one interpreter in my Pycharm

Comment: Maybe try installing Python 3.9

Answer (score 0):

Just run `pip install py-entitymatching` in the shell or terminal.

But if you are new to Python and you don't know about `pip` .

Select Pycharm's `Preferences` >> `Project` >> `Python Interpreter` >> set path of your **Python Interpreter** >> click Button`＋`  >> search `py-entitymatching`  >> install `py-entitymatching`

For example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried doing this as well but get the above error as shown in the image.